# Processing Data using Web Form

Tags: php, sql

I have a database that stores data input from a website. I have designed a form to retrieve some of the data from the database. My issue is, I want some of the form fileds to auto populate with data from certain table columns. i don't know the PHP code to insert into the form fileds to do this.

The form looks like this:
http://onlinestudentsadmission.com/schooldemo/studentsdataform.php

The table has the following columns: 
userid  last_name   first_name  year    friendly_url    has_pic     Gender  Orphan  Admmission School   County

I want the form to pull the data in year, County, and School columns and populate the field options. What code do I insert into those form fields?

The form submits to studentdatadisplay.php which am yet to code since I dont know how it should look like so as to get the data from the data retrieval form and format it to a table depending on the search criteria.

Any help will be appreciated alot.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML form inputs have the `name` attributes set, and your form action is actually posting to the right URL, you don't have to do anything else to your form.

Have a read through this guide for [PHP form handling](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp). Basically, the `name` attributes for each of your inputs will be an element in the `$_POST` object available to your in your future `studentdatadisplay.php` script. You'll do any database queries in that script file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about [drop-down list](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select3) that is automatically populated with the different values from a column (such as `year`, `County` or `School`)?

If so, the PHP at the top of your page should look something like this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","myDatabase");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$lookupYear = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT year AS value FROM tblStudents ORDER BY year ASC");
$lookupCounty = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT County AS value FROM tblStudents ORDER BY year ASC");
$lookupSchool = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT School AS value FROM tblStudents ORDER BY year ASC");
?>
```

Then when you're ready to list each one in the body HTML of your page, generate a dropdown option for each one using this example:

```
<select name="year">
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($lookupYear))
  {
  echo "<option value=\"" . $row['value'] . "\">" . $row['value'] . "</option>";
  echo "\n";
  }
?>
</select>
```

I hope that helps.